# How to make use of a .makerc file when running sudo make vs make?

Tags: macos, postgresql, makefile, sudo

I'm in the process of compiling a couple of Postgres extensions on a Snow Leopard installation (Postgres installed using MacPorts). This frequently requires two variables to be passed along with the make command, e.g.:

```
sudo make install USE_PGXS=1 PGUSER=postgres
```

My C is a bit rusty to say the least, and I've googled around to no avail in hopes of finding a means to not need to pass the above two variables.

I seem to have done a few things right... My current ~/.makerc file contains the following:

```
$ cat ~/.makerc 
USE_PGXS=1
PGUSER=postgres
```

This fixed the issue when running `make installcheck`, but running this without `sudo` frequently means permission problems down the road during the actual make process, and the `.makerc` isn't being read when I run `sudo make installcheck`. I logged in as root and placed a symbolic link in /var/root to the above file, to no avail.

I could arguably resort to doing all of this logged in as root. I'm curious to know if I might have overlooked something, however. Is there no means to make use of a `.makerc` file when running `sudo make` instead of `make`?

---

Edit: commented log, after the initial suggestion:

```
DB:~/pgdevel/kmeans-postgresql $ export USE_PGXS=1
DB:~/pgdevel/kmeans-postgresql $ export PGUSER=postrgess
```

This fails, because it makes the makefile assume that kmeans-postgresql is in postgres/contrib (which is what USE_PGXS is about, and placing it in postgres/contrib fails too because it was installed using MacPorts):

```
DB:~/pgdevel/kmeans-postgresql $ sudo make

Makefile:34: ../../src/Makefile.global: No such file or directory
Makefile:35: /contrib/contrib-global.mk: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `/contrib/contrib-global.mk'.  Stop.
```

This succeeds (even without the export):

```
DB:~/pgdevel/kmeans-postgresql $ make

sed 's,MODULE_PATHNAME,$libdir/kmeans,g' kmeans.sql.in >kmeans.sql
cp kmeans.sql kmeans--1.0.0.sql
/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -pipe -O2 -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wendif-labels -Wformat-security -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv  -I. -I. -I/opt/local/include/postgresql91/server -I/opt/local/include/postgresql91/internal -I/opt/local/include -I/opt/local/include/ossp -I/opt/local/include/libxml2  -I/opt/local/include  -c -o kmeans.o kmeans.c
[some warnings...]
/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -pipe -O2 -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wendif-labels -Wformat-security -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv  -L/opt/local/lib/postgresql91 -L/opt/local/lib -arch x86_64 -L/opt/local/lib  -L/opt/local/lib -Wl,-dead_strip_dylibs   -bundle -bundle_loader /opt/local/lib/postgresql91/bin/postgres -o kmeans.so kmeans.o
rm kmeans.o
```

PS: I'm re-adding the OSX and PostgreSQL tags because, while not strictly PostgreSQL related, I'm hoping another PostgreSQL user on MacOSX might know the workaround.

Comment: Where did you get that `.makerc` from? Is it GNU Make or something else?

Comment: Trial and error, really. I saw it mentioned in a Google result, so tried it. GCC version is i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5664)

Comment: I couldn't find it in the GNU Make docs, so probably it doesn't exist :)

Comment: Seems so. I just posted the answer, and indeed no such file was needed...

Comment: Extensions that require variables like that to be set are broken.  Send them a bug report.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sudo -E` preserves the environment.  Depending on your operating system and version, this was the default at some point, but might not be anymore.  So try

```
sudo -E make install
```

Answer (score 0):

The `sudo` shouldn't change current user environment, so all variables and access to homedir files are preserved. Maybe you should define a file like `setenv.sh`:

```
export USE_PGXS=1
export PGUSER=postrgess
```

And source it in your build shell:

```
$ . setenv.sh
```

Or you can put it into your `.bashrc`, but that will be included in all your shells and in some time in the future you can get confused '*why this dammed Postgress gets compiled like that?*'

Comment: I just tried the export, to no avail. (Posted more verbose logs, too.)

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the right keywords to Google: "sudo export environment variable"...

This eventually led me to identify the `/etc/sudoers` file, which needs to be edited as root using the `visudo` command.

So, first, two lines are needed in the `~/.bash_profile` file:

```
export PGUSER=postgres
export USE_PGXS=1
```

The `vi` program is needed as an editor (`mate -w` didn't want to work for some reason), so the precise command for `visudo` is:

```
env EDITOR=vi sudo visudo
```

Add two lines after the environment reset:

```
Defaults        env_keep += "PGUSER"
Defaults        env_keep += "USE_PGXS"
```

Finally restart the terminal, and good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Denis, I use `tcsh(1)` nearly exclusively for exactly this reason. Different tools, projects, work environments, etc, all require different toolchains and therefore different environment variables. This different context, however, is almost always bounded by the directory that you're in.

Here's what I have in my `.cshrc` file (lines 100-116):

https://github.com/sean-/cshrc/blob/master/.cshrc#L100

And then I litter my file system with things like this:

https://github.com/sean-/flask-skeleton/blob/master/.enter.tcsh

or this:

https://github.com/sean-/Boost.Examples/blob/master/.enter.tcsh#L1

In the latter example where I want to support site-local settings in a distributed `.enter.tcsh` file, I add support for the convention of `.local.tcsh` and then I can provide my own settings (in this case, I use a copy of boost that's not in the standard location):

```
# My .local.tcsh file for the Boost.Examples project referenced above.
if ( ${?BOOST_INCDIR} == "0" ) then
  setenv BOOST_INCDIR $HOME/src/foo/obj/contrib-Darwin-i386/include
  printf '[INFO] Setting BOOST_INCDIR environment variable to %s\n' ${BOOST_INCDIR}
endif

if ( ${?BOOST_LIBDIR} == "0" ) then
  setenv BOOST_LIBDIR $HOME/src/foo/obj/contrib-Darwin-i386/lib
  printf '[INFO] Setting BOOST_LIBDIR environment variable to %s\n' ${BOOST_LIBDIR}
endif

if ( ${?DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH} == "0" ) then
  setenv DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH $HOME/src/foo/obj/contrib-Darwin-i386/lib
  printf '[INFO] Setting DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable to %s\n' ${DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH}
endif
```

I hope the tip helps (using `tcsh(1)` over `bash(1)` has saved me gazillions of hours of frustration and debugging time... the history is what really won me, but that's a different story). It's stuff like this that makes `tcsh(1)` my preferred shell for interacting with systems (I still script in `sh` where necessary).

As for your specific situation:

```
sudo env PGUSER=postgres USE_PGXS=1 make install
```

or since you're on a mac using MacPorts (my native dev env):

```
sudo env PGUSER=postgres USE_PGXS=1 PATH=/opt/local/lib/postgresql91/bin:${PATH} make install
```

Comment: Thanks taking the time to write all of this. The lines you were suggesting at the very end were precisely those I was seeking to avoid to write each time. ;-) I actually managed to avoid them altogether by editing the /etc/sudoers file using visudo.

Comment: np. I don't like putting what feels like one-off items in system global areas, which is why I developed the technique of `.enter.tcsh` and `.local.tcsh`. Context local hints for what I did in the past can't be beat, esp now that my brain is apparently filling up and I'm prone to needing documentation or notes. >< LMK if you have any questions though.

Comment: Context-dependent shell settings are also possible with zsh.  But in any case, this doesn't really help here, because he might be downloading some random extension into a temporary directory that a shell configuration won't necessarily predict.

Comment: Correct. Incidentally, I got the idea from zsh, but zsh isn't installed on most systems by default.